# Re arranging Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

it may be a simple thing, but i am not able to get around it. Kindly have a look.

I have a data frame test.csv, as shown in figure below.

```
head(test)

  TYPE  ABC_1 ABC_2 ABC_3 XYZ_1 XYZ_2 XYZ_3
1  all    12    71    42     4     6    45
2    F    21    75    32     1     3   544
3    G    35     5   757     5     5    12
4    M    25     5     7     9     7    77
5    P    52    24    75     7     8     4
6    R    12    24     8    74     9    65
```

I am trying to rearrange the data frame like this.

```
   TYPE TYPE1 X1 X2  X3
1   all   ABC 12 71  42
2   all   XYZ  4  6  45
3     F   ABC 21 75  32
4     F   XYZ  1  3 544
5     G   ABC 35  5 757
6     G   XYZ  5  5  12
7     M   ABC 25  5   7
8     M   XYZ  9  7  77
9     P   ABC 52 24  75
10    P   XYZ  7  8   4
11    R   ABC 12 24   8
12    R   XYZ 74  9  65
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: `result <- tidyr::pivot_longer(test, cols = -TYPE, names_to = c('TYPE1', '.value'), names_sep = '_')`

Comment: @RonakShah thanks Ronak, i am little bit confused between names seperation